# ps aux shows only processes of the current user

Tags: linux, debian, ps

On one of my servers running Debian 7.8, when I run `ps aux`, I only see processes belonging to the current user.

If I check the permissions with `sudo ls -al /proc/`, procesess run by root have theses permissions:
`dr-x------`
Whereas on my other Debian boxes, I have this: `dr-xr-xr-x`

Do you know what could cause this and how I can change it?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the 'hidepid' option to the mounted /proc filesystem.

Check `grep proc /proc/self/mounts`. If `hidepid=1` or `hidepid=2`, remove the mount option and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't have a hidepid option:
`proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the hidepid=0 in /etc/fstab just to see what happens. Add this line to /etc/fstab and reboot.

```
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=0
```

It would be interesting to see if the problem persists with hidepid actually set to zero.

Running debian 7.8 with the above stanza in /etc/fstab "mount | grep -i proc" does not show hidepid option actually set to 0.

If I set it to 1, then the hidepid option is shown

```
morgan@debian:~$ mount | grep -i proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=1)
```

However, even with "hidepid=1", and "ps aux" only showing the procesess for the current user, permissions for the /proc/PID directories are still 555 not 500.

```
root@debian:/proc# mount | grep -i proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=1)
root@debian:/proc# ls -al | head
total 4
dr-xr-xr-x 80 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root        root                   4096 Jul 26 08:43 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 1
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 10
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 108
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 11
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 110
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 119
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root        root                      0 Jul 26 14:33 12
```

A similar question was asked here, for ubuntu 10.04

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173093

However, even running ubuntu 10.04 with kernel 2.6, the /proc/PID permissions were still 555, not 500.